# Object oriented table layout in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my case I'm looking to make a simple asset register.

All items will have some kind of serial/model number, description, date purchased, still active, etc.

But certain items will have extra data about them, for example 
Phones will have an IMEI number and phone number, contract length. 
Laptops will have a serial number, OS. 
Vehicles will have a registration, VIN, MOT/Service date. Factory equipment will have a calibration date

What I'm after (I think) is a way to do object-oriented tables so all Objects are an asset and each type has its own characteristics as well.

Am I best off having separate tables for each type of asset? Or redundant columns in one main table. I figured it would be best as in the image, but is there a better way? If the way in the image is best - how would I do the link to ignore blank columns in the tables that aren't needed (e.g. the IMEI number on a car asset)

[image: ERD]

Comment: Make whatever comes first on your mind, gain experience, do refactoring, repeat. If you don't see any obvious caveats - go forward until you discover any. Each solution has it's own pros and cons.

Comment: Don't just try whatever comes to mind. Think about the requirements and consequences. You don't want create a bad schema just to satisfy *one* application, or one object model in that application. How are you going to handle *reporting* for example? ORMs offer multiple ways to handle inheritance - table per concrete type (separate tables for laptops and phones), table per *sub*type (one asset table and separate phone, laptop tables), table per hierarchy (one table for all assets with optional values).

Comment: TPH is easier to use when there are a lot of subtypes but makes validation *hard* since optional columns have to be null and can't have constraints that may contradict another subtype. What you posted here is table-per-subtype or table-per-subclass. It makes sense when the root type has a lot of common info. But does that info belong to *asset*? `PurchaseDate` looks like an attribute that should be part of a `Purchases` or `Inventory` table. `Active` may or may not belong to the asset itself. Do you care about retirement dates perhaps?

Comment: Table-per type/table-per-concrete class would work just as well if the common fields are few. It would make reading individual types faster as well. It would be *slower* though if you wanted to find eg all assets due for retirement in the next month, or all assets assigned to an employee. On the other hand, that's a clear sign you need an Assignment class/Table. But how would you ensure `AssetID` is always valid? You can't add FKs to *all* tables. Perhaps that separate `Asset` type is useful after all?

Comment: Or perhaps, you don't really care about the extra information, now *or in the future*? Perhaps it's only for display/reference purposes? A quick solution In this case you could stuff it into an XML/JSON field and handle serialization in your client code. That's TPH again.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Following your descriptions - I definitely think table-per type is the way to go for what I'm doing. Is there any way round the issue that DaMachk mentioned in his answer? In this scenario - how would you select all assets? I can't think of an elegant way to display all assets regardless of type without either ignoring the subclass specific data or running a completely separate query to show the extra information then combining them in UI afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it in a relational database is to have a M:N relationship between asset and "properties" or stuff you want to have included.

Then you normalise it with a 1:N:1 middle table.

So basically, you have an asset with basic data (ID, name, date of purchase or something), and have the extended properties in a separate table.

See picture here:
[image]

Because you don't want to access a new table every time you want to access an asset information, but you rather have it all in one place and gather the data out from it.